# Can't sent email exchange RPC  HTTP

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

Ok so I tried in so many ways to sent this email but i just cannot get, this are the only two given by provider of the service

**the url of the exchange Server**

`EXVMBX016-3.exch016.msoutlookonline.net`

**proxy to connect over http**

`dc016-8.exch016.msoutlookonline.net`

**NOTE: I tried with SSL**

Now my problem it's that in the default port which i'm understand it's `25` the connection it's refused so i opened my outlook and with a sniffer i tried to see what's the port opened in that url, it was `135` give's a timeout.

```
 System.Net.NetworkCredentialnetworkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@example.com", "*****");
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
 message.To.Add("example@example.com");
 message.Subject = "Esto es una prueba de direccion";
 message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("example@example.com");
 message.Body = "Esto es una prueba del servicio de direcciones";
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("EXVMBX016-3.exch016.msoutlookonline.net");
 //smtp.Port = 135
 //smtp.EnableSsl = False
 smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 smtp.Credentials = networkCredentials;
 smtp.Send(message);
```

So If Do i miss something?. or What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Here's some images of my configuration on outlook

[image: server Url]

[image: Proxy]

Comment: have you tried already to send an email with telnet? Perhaps connection refused on port 25 (port of the smtp protocol)?

Comment: i didn't let me tried and i tell you later

Comment: still looking for a answer... But talking with infrastructural department seems to be a problem with the provider of the service

Comment: you must need to correct SMTP address to send email. I tested your exact code with correct SMTP address and it worked without any problem so your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using wrong SMTP Address. Based on my understanding an Exchange Server name can not be  SMTP name cEXVMBX016-3.exch016.msoutlookonline.net. Your SMTP Server Address will be different then what have you used above and that's why the connection is refused. When sending any email you just need correct SMTP address and proper credentials to connect it, that's it. I believe your code is correct.

To get correct SMTP address, open your email address contact card in Outlook and then look for "Email Address" properties and there you will get correct SMTP address and use in above code.

**[Added Later after above images are added]**

Based on above images, you are using Exchange Server Address as SMTP address which is wrong. You must get the correct SMTP address from your IT and then use that to send your email. Your code is right so correct SMPT address will work immediately.

Comment: Already checked and that's url of outlook have in tyhe configuration that's why is a mystery for me about why this doesn't work

Comment: Can u capture the screen shoot and blur all the info besides SMTP, then share here?

Comment: I added the changes in the question

Comment: Please contact your IT and ask them to provide you correct SMTP address and then use that to send email.